# How to breed Leviathan Dragon in Dragon City?

Tags: dragon-city

I'm trying hard to get Leviathan Dragon in Dragon City. I'm was pairing war dragon with sea dragon, then with many dragons with sea element. Then I've tried other war dragons (for example Juggernaut) with sea dragon, or with dragons with sea element. Many tries, but no result.

What I'm doing wrong? Which dragons should I pair to get my Leviathan Dragon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google search will find you this site:[Leviathan Dragon.](http://www.dragoncityegg.net/how-to-breed-leviathan-dragon-in-dragon-city/)

> > To breed the Leviathan Dragon, you will have to use a sea hybrid and a war hybrid to get it. Below are some combinations that will give you
> >     a shot at this rare hybrid.
>
> Colossal(War+Terra) + Mercury(Sea+Metal)
>
> Nenufar(Sea+Nature) + Juggernaut(War+Flame)
>
> Red Woods(War+Nature)+Plankton(Terra+Sea)
>
> Red Woods(War+Nature)+ Waterfall(Sea+Terra)
>
> If you would like to see the full breeding chart, [click here](http://www.dragoncityegg.net/dragon-city-breeding-guide/).

Answer (score 1):

By breeding the double sea dragon (if you have it) with the war dragon, you should get a leviathan dragon with a 100% chance success.

The chances of getting a leviathan are quite low in general, and options from other answers could work, but the chances of getting one are quite rare (considering the dragon is very rare).

Answer (score 0):

I got it by breeding the High Fallen Dragon with the Beach Dragon. First time I've bred those two and got it.

Answer (score 0):

I got from the first time by breadin mars dragon with elfic dragon and both of them are level 10